# Python launch program from Maya freeze

Tags: python, maya

I have a little question. Maybe it's not difficult but I don't find the answer.

I find a way to launch from Maya substance painter with python command.

My problem is that Maya stays freeze until I leave substance painter.

I would like to use Maya while substance painter is open.

the code:

```
subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files/Allegorithmic/Substance Painter/substance painter.exe' ,'--mesh' , 'c:/temp/exported.fbx'])
```

Thank in advance for your help.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` waits for the completion of the subprocess. You should try `subprocess.Popen()`.